# OpenGL bool uniform?

Tags: c++, opengl, boolean, shader

I'm trying to send a boolean to an OpenGL glsl shader.

Currently I have this in the shader:

```
uniform bool foo;
```

And I use this to set it:

```
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader, "foo"), true);
```

There doesn't seem to be a `glUniform1b`, so I'm setting it as an integer. This seems to work fine.

**Is there any problem with this approach? Is it portable, or could it break on other graphics cards / drivers?** I'm using OpenGL 4.3 at the moment.

Comment: As far as I know it has something to do with 4-byte alingment (boolean is 1 byte so either way 3 additional padding bytes will be added at the end) so using boolean is not efficient and maby even deprecated in OpenGL

Comment: @Amadeusz it's certainly not deprecated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> **§ 4.1 Basic Types** 
>   The OpenGL Shading Language supports the following basic data types, grouped as follows:
>
> - `bool` a conditional type, taking on values of true or false
> - `bvec2` a two-component Boolean vector
> - `bvec3` a three-component Boolean vector
> - `bvec4` a four-component Boolean vector

...

> **§ 4.1.2 Booleans** To make conditional execution of code easier to express, the type bool is supported. There is no expectation that hardware directly supports variables of this type. (...)

As for setting:

> **§ 2.2.1** (...) When state values are specified using a different parameter type than the actual type of that state, data conversions are
>   performed as follows:
>
> - When the type of internal state is boolean, zero integer or floating-point values are converted to `FALSE` and non-zero values are converted to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks. 4.1 means that I can use bool in my glsl shader. 4.1.2 doesn't really help me. What is still not answered is if I can set a boolean uniform using glUniform1i...

Comment: @JanRüegg Added a quote for that as well

Answer (score 0):

The size of a glsl `bool` is 32-bits which is identical to an `int`, so yes, you can set it like that.

And no, it won't break on other graphics cards / drivers for OpenGL.

Comment: *"integer below or equal to zero is considered false"* The other answer claims that non-zero integers are always false. *"bool occupies 1-byte"* I'm not sure about it, the other answer claims that *"no expectation that hardware directly supports variables of this type"*.